# getting error in display values in Xcode from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json, xcode

hi i am trying to get values from mysql to display in Xcode textfield.but i got (null) values in text field..
my Xcode ...

```
- (IBAction)find:(id)sender {
    NSError *err;
    NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.15:81/priya/sam.php?FirstName=%@",name.text];
    NSData *dataURL=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    NSString *strResult=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"got response==%@", strResult);
    NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
    NSArray *array=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"key"];
    address.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"firstName"]];
    phone.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[array objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:@"lastname"]];
}
```

and my php code..

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "xcode"; 
$pass = "xcode"; 
$db="xcode";
$r = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
echo mysql_get_server_info() . "\n"; 
$r2 = mysql_select_db($db);
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE FirstName='{$_GET['FirstName']}'");
$result=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    array_push($result,array('firstName' => $row[0],'lastname'=>$row[1]));

echo json_encode(array("key" => $result));

mysql_close();
?>
```

and also i got JSON values in console

```
 {"key":[{"firstName":"Peter","lastname":"Griffin"},{"firstName":"Peter","lastname":"Griffin"}]}
```

help me to find answer for this . thanks in advance.

Comment: The code seems good. May be issue is somewhere else.

Comment: i got (null) in textfield

Comment: Do NSLog of values you get from array. Are you getting null in NSLog

Comment: thank you there i got NSException.

Comment: i got NSDictionary null. please tell what error in my code

Comment: Do a NSLog on [error localizedDescription] this might help.

Comment: if any tutorial is there for this means please tell me .

Comment: Read on apple developer website. It's best reference doc.