# how to get JSONarray values in Xcode to display in textfield?

Tags: php, ios, json

i know this is very old question to ask here.but i am very new to this concept .so only i am asking..
here is my php code

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "xcode"; 
$pass = "xcode"; 
$db="xcode";

$r = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if (!$r) {
echo "Could not connect to server\n";
trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
echo "Connection established\n"; 
}

echo mysql_get_server_info() . "\n"; 
$r2 = mysql_select_db($db);

if (!$r2) {
echo "Cannot select database\n";
 trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
echo "database selected\n"; 
}

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");

$result=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))

array_push($result,array('firstName' => $row[0],'lastname'=>$row[1]));
echo json_encode(array("key" => $result));


mysql_close();

 ?>
```

and my console value

```
Connection established 5.5.34 database selected {"key":[{"firstName":"Peter","lastname":"Griffin"},{"firstName":"Glenn","lastname":"Quagmire"},{"firstName":"Peter","lastname":"Griffin"},{"firstName":"Glenn","lastname":"Quagmire"}]}
```

i need to get this values in text field in Xcode like
first name:Praia
lastname:kavi
 thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to get it from server, parse and put into textfields. it's very easy

Comment: i am done but i got null value in text field

Comment: so find where exactly you lose it. You have json from server and see it? you parse it and see parsed data?

Comment: and btw why did you put this php code here? what for? isn't it better to show objective-c client-side code instead?

Comment: alredy i poste my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037255/getting-error-in-display-values-in-xcode-from-mysql here

Comment: and do not ask one question twice anymore

Comment: i do not  know what error i made. morning onwards i stuck in there so only i repost again .soory

Comment: if any tutorials are available means give link.thank you

Comment: tell me where exactly you stuck. what do you see here -  NSLog(@"got response==%@", strResult);?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you ask for here, so I'll include code for both downloading the JSON and the code for setting the objects of the JSON to UITextFields.

Code for downloading the JSON object:

```
- (id)makeURLRequestWithString:(NSString *)url {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                            timeoutInterval:10];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    // Make synchronous request
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                            returningResponse:&response
                                                        error:&error];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    if (urlData) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&error];
        return dict;
    } else return error;
}
```

Code for calling the web request and get the result:

```
- (IBAction)requestJSON:(id)sender {
    dispatch_queue_t jsonParsingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("jsonParsingQueue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{ //Do request on another queue to prevent it from blocking UI
        id result = [self makeURLRequestWithString:@"http://www.blablabla.com/blabla.php"]; //Remember to include "http://"
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(results:) withObject:result waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)results:(id)result {
    //Check if the id is an NSDictionary, otherwise treat it as an error
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSArray *key = [result objectForKey:@"key"];
        NSDictionary *firstName = [key firstObject];
        self.yourFirstTextField.text = [firstName objectForKey:@"firstName"];
        self.yourSecondTextField.text = [firstName objectForKey:@"lastname"];

        //OR use this code to get all first and last names in the same UITextField:
        for(NSDictionary *dict in key) {
            self.yourTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@", self.YourTextField.text, [dict objectForKey:@"firstName"], [dict objectForKey:@"lastname"]];
        }
    } else {
        //An NSError is returned. Handle it.
    }
}
```

I copied this code from one of my own projects and made some modifications to it to fit this task, but beware that there might be some typos or a simple logical error :-)

Edit:
I have very little PHP experience, so if some special POST or GET request or something else is required to make the server send the JSON, the `makeUrlRequestWithString`method must be modified to adapt to this.